# Spring Kafka Client unable to get messages from a Kerberos enabled Kafka Broker topic

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We recently have our Kafka cluster kerberized and we started having issues reading messages from the topic on the broker.

We are using spring kafka 1.1.2.RELEASE and kafka client 0.10.0.1.

I have made the following changes in the project after going through the suggestions from Apache Kafka's documentation.

1. Added security.protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT in the consumer properties.
2. Added the appropriate JAAS file and provided the path in the VM arguments.
3. Added the KRB5.conf and provided the path in VM arguments.
4. I have the appropriate keytab entry created and supplied in the JAAS file as well.

Post this changes, i am able to bring up the application with no issues (no errors in DEBUG OR TRACE) and i see in the logs that connection to the broker was successful.
I also checked the TCP connections and it shows that the client and the server are communicating well.

However, the problem is i am unable to receive messages from the topic and do not see any errors in the logs.

Is there something i am missing or any other way i could troubleshoot?

Comment: In the recent release we have added Kerberos configuration to the Spring Kafka: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/201. But looks like that fully unrelated to your problem. Check Kafka Broker logs for some clues.

Comment: Yes, i have asked my kafka admin to set the log level to DEBUG on the broker. I will update with my findings.

Comment: Ok - Looks like the kafka admin has temperorarily elevated the permissions on my ID to be able to recieve the messages from the topic. Still investigating the root cause though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - We have now resolved this by having our kafka admin setup the right ACLs (permissions) for the kerberos principal for the right consumer group and the right topic.

Refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Authorization+Command+Line+Interface for more information